# Remove referenced entity if event date has passed

Tags: entities

I have an organic group that can support events created by users (all users, not only group members).

In my event node there's a block that shows supporting ogs(Referencing entity) and in my og group node another block showing supported events(Referenced entity).

Og group admins can select which events to support using a select box.

I did this using Entity Reference and Everything works fine.

The question is: how can i automaticaly remove the supported events (the referenced entity) from the og group block and from the select box data when the event date has passed.

I try using rules but with no luck, this is my first project with Drupal, just started using the platform a week ago.
Thank you.

Comment: Do you need to remove the reference to historical events? Can you not just filter the supported events block so that it only shows events in the future?

Comment: Yes, That solution works fine, Thank you very much.